# how to run multiple sql statements in airflow jinja template using jdbc hook

Tags: sql, jinja2, airflow

Trying to run a hive sql using jdbchook and jinja template through airflow. Template works fine for a single sql statement but throws a parsing error with multiple statements.

- DAG

  ```
  p1 = JdbcOperator( 
  task_id=DAG_NAME+'_create',
  jdbc_conn_id='big_data_hive',
  sql='/mysql_template.sql',
  params={'env': ENVIRON},
  autocommit=True,
  dag=dag)
  ```
- Template

  ```
  create table {{params.env}}_fct.hive_test_templated
  (cookie_id string
  ,sesn_id string
  ,load_dt string)
  ;

  INSERT INTO {{params.env}}_fct.hive_test_templated
  select* from {{params.env}}_fct.hive_test
  ;
  ```

> Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 7:0 missing EOF at ';' near ')'

The template queries works fine when I run it in Hue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tobi is correct, the easiest way to do this is to parse your SQL statement into a list of SQL's and execute them sequentially.

The way that I do this is by using the sqlparse python library to split the string into a list of SQL statements and then pass them down to the hook (inherits dbapi hook) - the dbapi base class accepts a list of SQL statements and executes the sequentially, this could easily be implemented in the hive hook too. In the following example my "CustomSnoqflakeHook" inherits from the dbapi hook and the `run` method in the dbapi hook accpets a list of SQL statements :

```
    hook = hooks.CustomSnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.snowflake_conn_id)
    sql = sqlparse.split(sqlparse.format(self.sql, strip_comments=True))
    hook.run(
        sql,
        autocommit=self.autocommit,
        parameters=self.parameters)
```

From the dbapi hook:

```
def run(self, sql, autocommit=False, parameters=None):
        """
        Runs a command or a list of commands. Pass a list of sql
        statements to the sql parameter to get them to execute
        sequentially
        :param sql: the sql statement to be executed (str) or a list of
            sql statements to execute
        :type sql: str or list
        :param autocommit: What to set the connection's autocommit setting to
            before executing the query.
        :type autocommit: bool
        :param parameters: The parameters to render the SQL query with.
        :type parameters: mapping or iterable
        """
        if isinstance(sql, basestring):
            sql = [sql]

        with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
            if self.supports_autocommit:
                self.set_autocommit(conn, autocommit)

            with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
                for s in sql:
                    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
                        s = s.encode('utf-8')
                    self.log.info(s)
                    if parameters is not None:
                        cur.execute(s, parameters)
                    else:
                        cur.execute(s)

            if not getattr(conn, 'autocommit', False):
                conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @SimonD
Due to restart-ability issue, i'm considering going with separate tasks.

Comment: Why is restart-ability any issue if you have one task executing multiple statements?

Comment: If an Airflow task with multiple statements fails halfway through, I believe upon rerunning that task it starts from the beginning processing all statements again! 
Im not sure if there is a bookmark as such where it would resume from the failed statement.

Comment: To get around this you can use transactions, each statement being executed should be executed in one session. So the first statement will open a transactions and the last one will either commit or rollback, you just need to make sure you don't close your cursor or end your session between each statement (that's easy).

Comment: Thanks @SimonD. This is great information. I will read more about it and see if I can implement transactions with sql templates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Hue parses the statement differently. Sometimes there are statement separators implemented which allow this to happen.

Airflow seems not to have those separators.

So the easiest way would be to separate the two statements and execute those statements in two separate tasks.

Comment: Thanks @tobi6 
I realized that restart-ability would be an issue. Hence separate tasks is the way to go.